# How to start multiple Gazebo simulations with own rosmasters

Tags: gazebo-all-versions, ros-kinetic

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello!

I am just trying to train my algorithm to navigate without colliding with obstacles. Here I am using a RL algo that is trained with the corresponding gazebo world. The problem is now, that with highest real time update rate, one simulation with 5000 episodes needs about 25h. I now checked out htop and the performance or the graphics is always concentrated on one core.
That why I am now trying to find out, how to get multiple simulations running in parallel. My goal is then to better use the capacity of my PC to have more simulations done in the same time.
I first checked out [this](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15897/how-to-open-several-gazebos-in-a-linux-operating-system/) and [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/193062/how-to-run-multiple-independent-gazebo-instances-on-the-same-machine/) page to be able to get more than one gazebo simulation and rosmaster running in parallel.

Here comes my first question. I can copy the commands from those websites to get multiple simulations and rosmasters. But how can I tell one rosmaster, that he has to communicate with a certain gazebo node (especially, if the /gazebo messages can not be changed and are thus the same for the simulations)?

My second question is about the multimaster_fkie package. I am quiet new to that one and I found [this](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/22671/what-are-the-drawbacks-of-running-multiple-gazebo-simulations-using-multimaster-fkie-package/) page. There my goal is achieved of having seperate simulations. Can this package be used to tell a rosmaster to communicate only with one gazebo simualtion so that I can have more simulations in total with different rosmasters?

Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23833/how-to-start-multiple-gazebo-simulations-with-own-rosmasters/) by [Tima15](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/12751/tima15/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Okay,
the first answer is correct despite of two small things:

1. for the second tab it must be rosrun fkie_master_discovery master_discovery _mcast_group:=224.0.0.251. I think the documentary is maybe a bit old.
2. For the second tab in the second terminal it should be rosrun fkie_master_discovery master_discovery _mcast_group:=224.0.0.252 _mcast_port:=11512 to prevent same adress compared to the first terminal

---

Originally posted by [Tima15](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/12751/tima15/) with karma: 3 on 2019-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0